# Class Variable Returning Incorrectly?

Tags: python, class, flask

I'm using a class to have shared variables across flask routes.

```
class Manager():
    def __init__(self):
        self.passwords = []
```

```
    def setRestock(self, password: str, copies: str):
        self.passwords.append(password)
```

This is part of the code of my class. After I set the value of self.passwords with a few passwords, it looks something like this:

```
['testpassword1', 'testpassword2', 'testpassword3']
```

I've created a route which returns the value of self.passwords

```
@bp.route('/getPasswords', methods=['GET'])
def getPasswords():
    return jsonify({
        'status': 'ok',
        'data': manager.passwords
    }), 200
```

The expected result should be:

```
{"data":['testpassword1', 'testpassword2', 'testpassword3'],"status":"ok"}
```

When i make requests to that route, the expected result shows up but after every 5-6 requests, it randomly returns `{"data":[],"status":"ok"}`. Then making the request again returns the correct thing.

My problem is self.passwords is being returned as `[]` randomly and it's causing the HTML page to have issues. Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Comment: If you want stuff to persist across multiple HTTP calls, write it to a file or a database. HTTP calls are generally stateless.

Comment: I'll have over 10k people on my site at once and it will have to keep reading the file or database, If i keep reading to a file or database it's very resource demanding and not efficient

Comment: your route refers to `manager.passwords` but what is `manager`? where is it defined? Also you really have 10k people using your site that is sending them all the same list of passwords over a plain get requests?

Comment: Allow me to elaborate: that's not how this works. Unless you create a persistent session, HTTP calls are stateless. There are good reasons for this. If you want 10k users to see the same thing, *stick it in a proper persistent data store*, i.e. a database, and read it back from that store on each request. There is no webserver that is going to work the way you are expecting. I'm assuming that you are currently using the flask dev server, this problem will only get worse when you start running it in production with a WSGI server like gunicorn.

Comment: @IceDude try to provide the full code that you are working with, there is no way of knowing what is happening to `manager.passwords` if you do not mention the code interacting with it. As stated above, REST apis are meant to be stateless, so you explicitly need to store the things you want to persist. Also 10k is not a very huge number of people to be using a web service at once, depending of course on your infrastructure, most database systems will work just fine with that kind of load. what you need to worry about is why are you making an endpoint to get a list of passwords in plaintext?

Answer (score 0):

Using a global variable to hold state will work only under narrow circumstances.

The flask development server likes to restart itself if it detects changes, which is probably what you occasionally see `[]`. You can try running with `--no-reload` to disable that behavior.

If you're prototyping and want automatic reloading, then instead of using a global, try keeping the data in a file that you read (and write) on demand. If you're concerned about performance, try it. You might be pleasantly surprised.